# StaxEventItemWriter eliminating the <root> added by start/end Document methods

Tags: spring-batch

I have created a spring-batch job. My reader class reads the data from the DB and gives back the dataset object having the below structure.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder = { "start", "end", "users"})
public class DataSet implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Start datetime of this data set
     */
    private Date start;

    /**
     * End datetime of this data set
     */
    private Date end;

    /**
     * Providers involved in this data set
     */
    private List<User> users;
}
```

etc...... and the writer wites the above data using StaxEventItemWriter.
The resulting xml contains two root tag elements.

```
<root>  //added by the startDocument and endDocument methods from stax writer. 
  <DataSet>......</DataSet>  // from the dataSet xsd annotation.
</root>
```

i need to eliminate the  with out overriding the startDocument and endDocument methods.

is there a way to  do it through the configuration. its urgent please.

my writer configuartion is given below.

```
<bean id="testrWriter" class="com.test.writer.TestWriter"
        scope="step">
<property name="testXMLWriter" ref="testXMLWriter" />
<property name="baseDirectory" value"#{jobParameters['baseDirectory']}"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="testXMLWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
   <property name="overwriteOutput" value="true" /> 
   <property name="marshaller" ref="testJaxb2Marshaller" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="testJaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
    <list>
             <value>com.test.service.dto.DataSet</value>
    </list>
   </property> 
</bean
```

Comment: So you basically want to produce non-valid XML, as you won't have a root element? :) Indeed, the functionality you've asked is not in. I wonder if StaX supports such documents (with no start tag) at all.

Comment: The startDocument and endDocument from StaxEventItemWriter adds the <root> </root> tags. but my requirement is the root element should be <Dataset>...</DataSet>. If I override the startDocument and endDocument methods in a class extending the StaxEventItemWriter and inject that class as the "testXMLWriter" then the expected result occurs.

Comment: With out overridng the same is it possible to eliminate the <root> by putting some configuration to any of the below beans.                                                               <bean id="testXMLWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
   <property name="overwriteOutput" value="true" /> 
   <property name="marshaller" ref="testJaxb2Marshaller" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="testJaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
    <list>....</list>
   </property> 
</bean

Comment: Fist of all, `overwriteOutput` is by default true. Second: you can't suppress root tag without overriding `startDocument()` and `endDocument()` unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure that your XML output is valid when you set the RootTagName as !-- -- ? When I try it, the last tag in my XML output is </!-- -->, so the XML isn't valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the root to `!-- --`

finally got a valid xml.

```
<bean id="delegateWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="someMarshaller" />
    <property name="overwriteOutput" value="true" />
    <property name="RootTagName" value="!-- --"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

I override the method endDocument(XMLEventWriter writer), when I set rootTagName = "!-- --" and then ignore the end root tag.

```
protected void endDocument(XMLEventWriter writer) throws XMLStreamException {
            //
    if(this.getRootTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("!-- --")){
        return;
    }
    String nsPrefix = !StringUtils.hasText(getRootTagNamespacePrefix()) ? "" : getRootTagNamespacePrefix() + ":";
    try {

        bufferedWriter.write("</" + nsPrefix + getRootTagName() + ">");
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new DataAccessResourceFailureException("Unable to close file resource: [" + resource + "]", ioe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, the solution that got me a valid XML was overring both methods `endDocument()` and `startDocument()`. But if you override `startDocument()`, you'll need to manually write the `<?xml ?>` header.

Answer (score 1):

Replying to the solution of @user2922056. You can't overwrite in that way (No access to bufferedWriter). Call the super method instead.

```
@Override
protected void endDocument(XMLEventWriter writer) throws XMLStreamException {
    if ("!-- --".equalsIgnoreCase(this.getRootTagName())) {
        return;
    } else {
        super.endDocument(writer);
   }
}
```

As the *RootTagName* has been setted before to the value `"!-- --"` the method `startDocument()`  will do the rest by adding a harmless comment in the xml.